# Understanding recursion in the beer bottle example

Tags: c, recursion, procedural

I am practicing recursion in C on my own and I found this example online.
However there is one thing I don't understand.

```
void singSongFor(int numberOfBottles)
{
if (numberOfBottles == 0) {
    printf("There are simply no more bottles of beer on the wall.\n\n");
} 
else {
    printf("%d bottles of beer on the wall. %d bottles of beer.\n",
           numberOfBottles, numberOfBottles);
    int oneFewer = numberOfBottles - 1;
    printf("Take one down, pass it around, %d bottles of beer on the wall.\n\n",
           oneFewer);
    singSongFor(oneFewer); // This function calls itself!

    // Print a message just before the function ends
    printf("Put a bottle in the recycling, %d empty bottles in the bin.\n",
             numberOfBottles);
   }
}
```

Then I use a main method as such:

```
 int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  singSongFor(4);
  return 0;
}
```

And the output is as such:

4 bottles of beer on the wall. 4 bottles of beer.
Take one down, pass it around, 3 bottles of beer on the wall.

3 bottles of beer on the wall. 3 bottles of beer.
Take one down, pass it around, 2 bottles of beer on the wall.

2 bottles of beer on the wall. 2 bottles of beer.
Take one down, pass it around, 1 bottles of beer on the wall.

1 bottles of beer on the wall. 1 bottles of beer.
Take one down, pass it around, 0 bottles of beer on the wall.

There are simply no more bottles of beer on the wall.

Put a bottle in the recycling, 1 empty bottles in the bin.

Put a bottle in the recycling, 2 empty bottles in the bin.

Put a bottle in the recycling, 3 empty bottles in the bin.

Put a bottle in the recycling, 4 empty bottles in the bin.

I understand the first part very well until I come to "There are simply no more bottles of beer on the wall. I don't understand afterwards how the variable number of bottles is incremented from 1 till 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the last `printf` uses the `numberOfBottles` variable, and that is never modified. So upon returning from printing `oneFewer` bottles, it will print the recycling text with `numberOfBottles`. Remember that there is one different incarnation of the local variables per each call to the function.

It can be seen easier if you indent the calls to the functions:

```
4 bottles of beer on the wall...
  3 bottles of beer on the wall...
    2 bottles of beer on the wall...
      1 bottles of beer on the wall...
        There are simply no more bottles of beer on the wall.
      Put a bottle in the recycling, 1 empty bottles in the bin.
    Put a bottle in the recycling, 2 empty bottles in the bin.
  Put a bottle in the recycling, 3 empty bottles in the bin.
Put a bottle in the recycling, 4 empty bottles in the bin.
```

Now, each line that begins in the same column is written from the same call of the function. Do you see how the number of bottles and recycling coindice? That's because both use the same variable: `numberOfBottles`.

Answer (score 6):

The smaller bottles of beer (and their corresponding recycling) are in inner functions. Your function tree looks like this:

```
4 bottles of beer on the wall. 4 bottles of beer. Take one down, pass it around, 3 bottles of beer on the wall.
|   3 bottles of beer on the wall. 3 bottles of beer. Take one down, pass it around, 2 bottles of beer on the wall.
|   |   2 bottles of beer on the wall. 2 bottles of beer. Take one down, pass it around, 1 bottles of beer on the wall.
|   |   |   1 bottles of beer on the wall. 1 bottles of beer. Take one down, pass it around, 0 bottles of beer on the wall.
|   |   |   |   There are simply no more bottles of beer on the wall.
|   |   |   Put a bottle in the recycling, 1 empty bottles in the bin.
|   |   Put a bottle in the recycling, 2 empty bottles in the bin.
|   Put a bottle in the recycling, 3 empty bottles in the bin.
Put a bottle in the recycling, 4 empty bottles in the bin.
```

Answer (score 4):

Step through what this is function is doing in a debugger and you will see exactly how this recursion works. I'm not being pedantic; I literally cannot think of any better way to illustrate what this is doing than referring to this interactive approach.

Comment: Iteration can help, and here is a good example, but sometimes I think it is easier to understand recursion from a higher level too, especially as things get more complex. For example, visiting a tree, or especially writing a recursive parser, looking at it as "tree.child IS a tree" makes the code simpler to understand (in my opinion anyway) than walking through it iteratively.

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe: However in this case, there would be no explanation needed if you stepped through this.

Answer (score 4):

Just a simple picture explaines:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The recycling statement runs after the recursive call returns.

Each of the recursion calls will eventually finish and the program will continue on to the recycling statement that follows, each with its own local variable values.

Answer (score 2):

With recursion, you can think of everything before the recursive call as being a forward loop, and everything after the call as being a backward loop. (Tail recursion - calling the function again at the end of the function - is often optimized by the compiler into a simple forward loop.)

The way this works is the arguments for each old function are pushed onto the stack, and popped when it all returns. Remember that a stack is last-in, first-out. So since you start with 4, it pushes 4, then 3, then 2, then 1. When the functions return, the stack starts unwinding, so you see the arguments again in reverse order: 1,2,3,4.

Comment: So, the concept of recursion always includes a stack as a data structure or is it just a way to explain the backward-forward loop mechanism ?
The stack is pretty clear. Does this apply to any programming language?

Comment: Yes, they'll always be a stack (of some sort - optimizations might change this in certain circumstances)) in there. When you call another function, the state of the outer function needs to be saved, so it can be resumed when the inner function finishes. This is done with a stack in any language (again, unless it gets optimized differently, but it still works the same way).

Answer (score 2):

The reason it works in this way is that every call of the `singSongFor()` where numberOfBottles is more than 1 will in turn recursively call `singSongFor()` until numberOfBottles is 0. At this point `printf("There are simply no more bottles of beer on the wall.\n\n")` is reached and that function will finish, passing up to the calling function, which will have had an argument of 1 passed in, which then reaches `printf("Put a bottle in the recycling, %d empty bottles in the bin.\n", numberOfBottles);` and itself completes, returning to `singSongFor(2)`... and so on until you're back at your original number, 4 in this case.