# How is this code skipping to the last string and reversing the stack?

Tags: c, stack

I'm studying `C` and it's a self-taught thing. It's great, but gets hairy when I have a question so I was hoping to get some help!

I have a bit of code that I was instructed to write and I understand the code, I understand how the stacks work (take one off, goes into another pile etc.) and that `main()` will always run first.

But what I don't understand is why, after the `numberOfBottles` reaches 0, it doesn't continue to loop. Why does it reverse the stack, firstly, and how is it jumping to the last string?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void singSongFor(int numberOfBottles)
{
    if (numberOfBottles == 0)
    {
      printf("there are simply no more bottles of beer on the wall. \n\n");
    } 
    else 
    {
        printf("%d bottles of beer on the wall. %d bottles of beer. \n", numberOfBottles, numberOfBottles);
        int oneFewer = numberOfBottles - 1;
        printf("Take one down, pass it around %d bottles of beer on the wall. \n\n", oneFewer);

        singSongFor(oneFewer);
        printf("Put a bottle in the recycling, %d empty bottles in the bin. \n", numberOfBottles);
    }
}
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    singSongFor(4);
    return 0;
}
```

So at the bottom of the `if/else` we have "put a bottle in the recycling" but the way I'm reading it is this:

```
4 take one down
3 take one down 
2 take one down 
1 take one down
0 "there are simply no more bottles..."
```

Now that it has reached 0, I would think it should just loop saying...
     "there are simply no more bottles..."
or, at very least, when it adds another bottle to the stack, why doesn't it say "Oh, I have 1 bottle again. Take one down?"

What is causing the code to go to the other stack that has built up and skip to "put a bottle..." from 1-4 and not go through the entire `if/else` again?

Comment: A pencil, piece of paper, and some indentation while jotting down the *value* of `numberOfBottles` within each call to `singSongFor` will do *wonders* in explaining how this works, especially for only 4 bottles. Pay close attention to what is *not* done when zero is reached.

Comment: This is a recursive function,  singSongFor is calling itself again and again until the number of bottles equals 0 and then it is exiting.  The 'stack' is the calling stack which will show the final printf as calls pop-off on the returns.

Comment: For more information, read http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson16.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding recursion in the beer bottle example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20714617/understanding-recursion-in-the-beer-bottle-example)

Comment: There is no "other stack". One stack gets created as you call the sing function repeatedly.  Then as the function calls finish, you move your way back up the stack again until you pop back out at main().

Comment: @WhozCraig that's what is confusing me I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [recursive function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29), which means it "loops" because it calls itself. When the function runs with an argument of 4, it calls itself again with an argument of 3. When it gets to zero, due to the `if` statement, it does not call itself again, and so the "loop" terminates, and control begins returning back up the chain of function calls.

> What is causing the code to go to the other stack that has built up and skip to "put a bottle..." from 1-4 and not go through the entire if/else again?

There is no "other stack." I think you're confusing yourself by thinking of stacks in this way. Just think of this as a function which keeps calling itself over and over until its argument is zero. If you were to draw out the sequence of nested function calls of this program, it would look like this (note this is a call stack diagram, not C code):

```
main()
{
    singSongFor(4)
    {
        // prints "4 take one down"
        singSongFor(3)
        {
            // prints "3 take one down"
            singSongFor(2)
            {
                // prints "2 take one down"
                singSongFor(1)
                {
                    // prints "1 take one down"
                    singSongFor(0)
                    {
                        // prints "0 there are simply..."
                    }
                    // prints "recycling 1"
                }
                // prints "recycling 2"
            }
            // prints "recycling 3"
        }
        // prints "recycling 4"
    }
    // end
}
```

Comment: So it's basically saying that it becomes singSongFor() with no argument?

Comment: @ElRojito I'm not really sure what you mean, but it doesn't "become" anything. If you understand the call stack diagram I drew, it should click in your mind; if not, you may want to brush up on the concepts of recursion and nested function calls (try the Wikipedia link I gave, or Google for tutorials).

Comment: Or wait, is it saying "numberOfBottles -1" then when it reaches 0 it re-calls itself 4 times and counts up to 4?

Comment: @ElRojito It doesn't call itself again. At the end of a function, control flow returns to the caller of that function. Since the function called itself (recursion), control returns to the same function, all the way back up the stack (see my drawing) until finally control returns out of the original signSongFor() function back to main().

Comment: Ok, so hopefully I'm starting to understand.  After the function finishes, the only line left to run (correct terminology? line?) is printf("%d \n", numberOfBottles); and number of bottles needs to run 4 times because in main it was told to do so and it can only run from 1->4 because the recursion ran it down from 4->0.

Comment: @ElRojito Yep, I think you have it now.

Answer (score 1):

You keep calling singSongFor before it ever gets to the printing of the Put a bottle in the recycling. And it eventually will hit the bottles == 0 and then it will not longer recursively loop because it cant reach the singSongFor call and end completely. Being a c# person i would suggest writing this as a for loop to be able to visualize it better and you will probably see your error in your recursion. Happy coding.