# Confused About Recursion (Bottles of Beer)

Tags: c, recursion

I was reading the explanations for:
[Understanding recursion in the beer bottle example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20714617/understanding-recursion-in-the-beer-bottle-example), but I still don't understand the last part of the singSongFor function. When it reaches the final printf, why does it not simply print that there are 0 bottles in the bin because numberOfBottles is 0 after it prints that there are no more bottles of beer on the wall. I don't understand why it starts at 1 and why it increments when there is nothing increasing the value of numberOfBottles.

Comment: Look at what is assigned to `oneFewer` *before* the invocation of `singSongFor(oneFewer)` (that variable not needed, btw, as you could simply invoke `singSongFor(numberOfBottles-1)` ).

Comment: So why does it not start at 4 then?

Comment: Nevermind. I managed to figure it out.